# Transmitter won't transmit with antenna installed

Tags: rfi

I built a node for my friend out of a baofeng BF-888s UHF transceiver.

I am powering the radio with a voltage regulator, and a few caps with a wall wart power supply.

The radio will transmit fine when there is a dummy load on the output, but when there is an antenna installed on the SMA connector, the radio will fail to transmit even though the transmit LED is on.

With a nearby receiver, the transmitter is heard only if I cover my hand over the antenna in a certain way, and even then, there is crazy 60hz hum on the transmit signal overloading the audio. **This 60 hz hum is not due to the lack of filter caps, the hum is not present with the dummy load on the antenna output.**

I tried putting an inductor in series with the positive lead of the power input, but that did not help. I powered the radio on battery, and it helped with the 60hz noise, but the radio would still not transmit until I cover the antenna with my hand.

I shielded the entire radio with aluminum foil, and that did help only if I touched my hand to the aluminum foil. I don't want aluminum foil over the whole radio for the final configuration, however.

The transceiver is plugged into with a USB sound card, and strange enough, even when the card is umplugged from my computers USB port, and manually cause the radio to transmit, the problem still exists.

Of course I could move the antenna far away with a coax extension, but then I could not have a compact portable node.

What is causing the radio to not transmit, any tips on eleminating RFI while keeping the transmit antenna near the radio?

Comment: Maybe your antenna is broken and the radio's protection circuity is doing its job?

Comment: Nope. Antenna is fine. The problem is even worse with a higher gain antenna screwed on the radio.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably getting the 60 Hz tone through your power supply OR the computer. Try the radio with a battery.  If no hum, then the problem is with your power supply. If still present, remove connection to computer and see if hum still present.